# C: Exporting large arrays with fprintf crashes compiler?

Tags: c, export

In C, I want to export a 1D array (of floats) to a CSV file to be opened by other programs. I wrote the following helper-function to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void float1DExportCSV(float *ptr, int n){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("FloatOutput.CSV", "w");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%f", ptr[i]);
        fprintf(f, "%c", ',');
    }
    fprintf(f, "%f", ptr[n-1]);
}
```

I then tried to test it on an array with 10 elements, like this:

```
#define n 10
int main(void){
    float array[n];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        array[i] = 4.3f*i;
    }
    float1DExportCSV(array, n);

    return 1;
}
```

This works fine, and the resulting file opens correctly. Changing `n` to larger numbers (up to around 400,000) also works fine.

However, somewhere around the 500,000-element mark, the program simply crashes upon building. The arrays I want to export to CSV have more than 500,000 elements. Is there a robust way of doing this type of export? Is a looping `fprintf` method like I used above simply not a good way of exporting a large dataset?

Comment: `float array[n];` : stack overflow.

Comment: Most likely you are running out of stack space. On linux you can see your stack space with ulimit -s. Likewise ulimit -s <number> increases your stack size to that number in kB.

Comment: Note that it is conventional to return `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` (from `<stdlib.h>`) from `main()` on success; `1` normally indicates failure. This won't affect the compiler; it won't affect the program crashing or not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Aha, so that must be why my code is crashing! :) On a more serious note, thanks for the tip (I'm just starting C).

Comment: Another side note: you can combine the two `fprintf`s in the loop into a single `fprintf` like this: `fprintf(f, "%f,", ptr[i]);`.  In other words, just put the comma after the `%f`.

Comment: The program or the compiler? Because the compiler should not crash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the array size is too large, use heap memory.

When `n` is too large, allocating the array on the stack causes stack overflow. At that time, allocating the memory on the heap is the answer.

Instead of

```
float array[n];
```

Use

```
float* array = malloc(n*sizeof(float));
```

Make sure to deallocate the memory. Add

```
free(array);
```

once you are done using the array.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had something to do with memory management problems, but I figured the problem was occurring during the `for`-loop, and didn't suspect that it was just the array allocation step itself! What memory limits are in place with heap memory? Is it just however much free memory your computer has?

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx,:  For ARM, x86 and x64 machines, the default stack size is 1 MB. For gcc, the values can be found at http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: Stack limits are platform-specific and often configurable. On Windows, I believe the limit is around 2 MiB (subject to contradiction by those who know better), but it is often larger (like 8 MiB) on Unix-based systems.  Specifically, the default on Mac OS X is 8192 KiB or 8 MiB.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Hmm, so heap limits are typically between 2MB to 8MB? That's weird, I just exported a 10,000,000-element float array (or approximately 40MB based on float size of 32 bits) without any apparent issues. Is there a Command Prompt command to query the heap limit?

Comment: Can't type - I meant 'Stack' but wrote 'Heap'; I was in time to fix my comment.

Comment: You can find the stack size (and other sizes) using `ulimit` with various options (`ulimit -a` shows the current soft limits; `ulimit -a -H` shows the hard limits).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that local variables are allocated on the stack. If you use a static or global variable for array it will be allocated in the .bss segment.  No need for malloc() or free() complexities for this simple test case.

```
#define n 500000
float array[n];  /* or static float array[n]; */
int main(void){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        array[i] = 4.3f*i;
    }
    float1DExportCSV(array, n);

    return 1;
}
```